# GAS: Debugging HTMLService

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am trying to use  the HTMLService to manage simple forms. This is an archetypal HTML form (`NATIVE` option is for portability):

`form.gs`:

```
function htmlTest (){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form');  
  html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Sample Form");
}
 
function cBack (el1, el2){
  Browser.msgBox('Data sent');
  Logger.log(el1);
  Logger.log(el2);
}
```

`form.html`:

```html
Enter field 1: <input name="name1"  id='input1'>
<br>
Enter field 2: <input name="name2" id='input2'>
<br>
<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='fParser()'>
 
<script>
 
function fParser() { 
   var el1=document.getElementById('input1').value;
   console.log(el1);
   var el2=document.getElementById('input2').value;
   console.log(el2);
   google.script.run.cBack(el1, el2);
   google.script.host.close();
}
</script>
```

*How can I debug efficiently a callback triggered from served HTML?*
What to do when a callback does not start?
I see that sometimes it is just a matter of closing and reopening the document to fix the problem: is there a more efficient way to reload the code?

Comment: You must refresh the browser tab every time you want to test new code.  I've never needed to close and reopen a document to text new code.

Comment: @SandyGood: are you sure that this is the rule always? or is it your personal habit? If I should refresh on every run, delivering even the simplest script would turn in a nightmare. PS. It seems to me that close/open by going back and forth to Sheets Home, is slightly faster than a whole refresh.

Answer (score 2):

I've found it easier to debug everything in the HTML page, to get back the variables use [withSuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)). This way you can keep editing the .gs and on the click of a button get the new results on the console.

Eg.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(debugging).cBack(el1, el2);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(debugging).anotherCallBacl(el);

function debbugging( logs ){
  console.log( logs );
}
```

and the .gs:

```
function cBack (el1, el2){
  Browser.msgBox('Data sent');
  return "el1 : " + el1 + " - el2: " + el2;
}
```